# Custom variable setter with a default value

Tags: swift

I cannot create a custom setter with a default value for this simple class.
I want to implement custom tz setter with timezone inspecting.

What's wrong?

```
public class City: NSObject {
    public var lat = 0.0, lon = 0.0, name = ""
    private static let def_tz = "GMT+00:00"
    private static let timezones = NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames()
    public var tz: String = def_tz {
        set { //// <<<<< There is the error
            var i = City.timezones.indexOf(newValue ?? City.def_tz) ?? 0
            self.tz = timezones[i].name
        }
        get {
            return self.tz
        }
    }
    // MARK:- Init

    required public init(name: String, lat: Double, lon: Double, tz: String) {
        super.init()
        setup(name, lat: lat, lon: lon, tz: tz)
    }

    private func setup(name: String, lat: Double, lon: Double, tz: String) {
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon

        self.tz = tz == "" ? City.def_tz : tz
        self.name = name
    }

}
```

The error is

> City.swift:16:9: Use of unresolved identifier 'set'

Comment: First of all `def_tz` and `timezones` are static and must be accessed with `City.def_tz`, second of all a setter does not return anything and `set` does not work together with a default value in the declaration line.

Comment: @vadian , 10x . changed the code. the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your custom setter is wrong here.

Check for the correct one here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
public var lat = 0.0, lon = 0.0, name = ""
private var _tz = def_tz
    private static let def_tz = "GMT+00:00"
    private static let timezones = NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames()
    public var tz: String {
        set {
            let i = City.timezones.indexOf(newValue ?? City.def_tz) ?? 0
            self._tz = City.timezones[i]
        }
        get {
         return self._tz
        }
    }
```